# string replace() method doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, methods, replace

I am trying to write a Python program that would fix the formatting of all links provided in a list from the user.

Every link should look like `"https://example.com"`. So I am using `replace` to replace the wrong parts with new ones. However the `.replace` method doesn't seem to work at all and I'm having a hard time finding out why.

I am trying to set this up as a function. This is my code:

```
from re import findall

def get_urls():
    # Gets urls from the provided string
    urls = input("Stream urls: ").split(",")
    for i, url in enumerate(urls):
        urls[i] = findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', url)
        if "https://www." in urls[i]:
            urls[i] = urls[i].replace("https://www.", "https://")
        elif "www." in urls[i]:
            urls[i] = urls[i].replace("www.", "https://")
        elif "http://" in urls[i]:
            urls[i] = urls[i].replace("http://", "https://")
        return urls

print(get_urls())
```

The output is printed back to me, but the links remain unchanged. There doesn't seem to be a typo or a direct syntax error in my code since the IDE doesn't report anything of that sort.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am using "from re import findall" so adding re. shouldn't be necessary I think.

Comment: `return urls` shouldn't be in the loop. You're returning after processing the first URL, the rest are unchanged.

Comment: your return is inside the loop so after just the first url it will return and wont process any other urls, do you mean that to be outside the loop?

Comment: I did actually. This happened when I was trying to "guess" the right combination out of pure sadness...

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code:

- `re.findall` returns a list, so `"https://www." in urls[i]` (and the 2 other checks) will likely always be `False`.
- You need to iterate over `urls` again, or just do not use `findall`. It looks like you can just use `startswith` or `re.match`.
- You are `return`ing inside the loop, which also does not look like what you meant to do.

```
def get_urls():
    # Gets urls from the provided string
    urls = input("Stream urls: ").split(",")
    for i, url in enumerate(urls):
        if url.startswith("https://www."):
            urls[i] = urls[i].replace("https://www.", "https://")
        elif url.startswith("www."):
            urls[i] = urls[i].replace("www.", "https://")
        elif url.startswith("http://"):
            urls[i] = urls[i].replace("http://", "https://")
    return urls
```

Comment: The findall is there because I need to detect wrong user input afterwards. If a user was to paste in 4 links for example and one of them wouldn't be I need to make sure that only the links get through. I am not sure how to do this filtering at all since any configuration results in a different problem pretty much.